# Split Column into multiple column when there is blank column

Tags: shell-script, awk, sed, gawk

I need some help:

```
A
B
C

1
2

Q
W
A
```

Whenever we find blank column split the column into new column.

Output:

```
A,1,Q   
B,2,W
C,,A
```

I have used Sed but I am not able to find keyword to split. Is there a way to do it effeciently as I have huge data.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
$ csplit -zsf file ip.txt /^$/+1 {*}
$ paste -d, file* | head -n -1
A,1,Q
B,2,W
C,,A
```

From manual:

> **csplit** - split a file into sections determined by context lines
>
> **-z, --elide-empty-files** remove empty output files
>
> **-s, --quiet, --silent** do not print counts of output file sizes
>
> **-f, --prefix=PREFIX** use PREFIX instead of 'xx'

> **paste** - merge lines of files
>
> **-d, --delimiters=LIST** reuse characters from LIST instead of TABs

`head -n -1` is used to remove the last line, you can also use `sed '$d'`

Comment: `ip.txt /^$/+1` ??

Comment: To make sure the empty line is at the end of the splits, otherwise, it will show up as part of the next split

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { RS=""; FS="\n"; OFS="," }
{
    numRows = (NF>numRows ? NF : numRows)
    numCols = colNr = NR
    for (rowNr=1; rowNr<=NF; rowNr++) {
        vals[rowNr,colNr] = $rowNr
    }
}
END {
    for (rowNr=1; rowNr<=numRows; rowNr++) {
        for (colNr=1; colNr<=numCols; colNr++) {
            printf "%s%s", vals[rowNr,colNr], (colNr<numCols ? OFS : ORS)
        }
    }
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
A,1,Q
B,2,W
C,,A
```

The above stores all input in memory so YMMV depending on what you mean by "huge" in `I have huge data` - if it's just a few million blank-line-separated blocks like in your input it'll be fine but if it's terabytes of data then maybe not.

Comment: +1: useful expos{ure,ition} of how exp{a,e}nsive it is to transpose a 2D matrix using `awk` in the shell. You really have a knack for this. ;-)

Comment: Yeah, you can do it with less code but I highly favor clarity over brevity, especially when answering questions on a forum, hence the meaningful variable names, variables used when not strictly necessary, etc.